# Is there a way to find out property names of application.properties file for a custom dependeny in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, configuration, dependencies

There are times when I use a whole new dependency in spring framework and I spend so much time to find out the correct properties to set in .yaml file or .properties file as configurations for that dependency. Is there a way to have a list or something of all you can set in those files for a dependency?

for example these are used for `spring.data.mongodb`:
`spring.data.mongodb.uri`,
`spring.data.mongodb.host`,
`spring.data.mongodb.port`,
`spring.data.mongodb.database` and 
`spring.data.mongodb.authenticationDatabase`.

Answer (score 0):

I think only your IDE can help you here. **IntelliJ** has an awesome **Spring/ Spring-Boot Integration**. Here is an example how it looks like when you use the autoconplete in IntelliJ:

[image]
<sub>(source: [reflectoring.io](https://reflectoring.io/assets/img/posts/spring-boot-configuration-properties/intellij.png))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot common application properties are listed [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) and can be used for quick reference.

Following sections are available under **Appendix A: Common Application properties** for the current Spring Boot version (2.3.0)

- 10.A.1. Core properties
- 10.A.2. Cache properties
- 10.A.3. Mail properties
- 10.A.4. JSON properties
- 10.A.5. Data properties
- 10.A.6. Transaction properties
- 10.A.7. Data migration properties
- 10.A.8. Integration properties
- 10.A.9. Web properties
- 10.A.10. Templating properties
- 10.A.11. Server properties
- 10.A.12. Security properties
- 10.A.13. RSocket properties
- 10.A.14. Actuator properties
- 10.A.15. Devtools properties
- 10.A.16. Testing properties